# SQL Server row base authorisation using ACL

Tags: sql-server, acl

Consider following  scenario a table where I want to store records. There should be permissions enabled on these records, similarly to file system. The users are stored in Active Directory and I want also to consider the user groups. The user comes and makes a simple select "select * from table" and he will see only the elements where he has permissions or alternatively the user makes a select "select * from table where user = 'username'" and he will get only the rows where he has permissions. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Google](http://bit.ly/AnZXBw) to find [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx):

> ## Implementing Row- and Cell-Level Security in Classified Databases Using SQL Server 2005
>
> Summary: This paper describes how SQL Server 2005 can be used to support row- and cell-level security (RLS/CLS). The examples provided in this white paper show how RLS and CLS can be used to meet classified database security requirements.

Simply implement row-level security with your chosen ACL methodology: you can associate SQL users with Active Directory users or groups, and T-SQL has functions for exposing a user's group membership.